# Media Player - Show custom Time Code

Tags: vb.net, media-player, timespan

I am trying to make a video player for a project which seems to be quite a challenge when I came to a stage where I need to show a time code (sort of time stamp) in a label next to the video being played.

The function of the program is...The movie file name contains the recording start time of the movie file in the format "17:56:33_Camera01.avi". When I load the movie in the player using the URL and click play the movie plays. I use a timer to get the current position of the playback in seconds,minutes and hours using the below method in the timer tick sub.

```
Dim PlayHour, PlayMin, PlaySec As Integer
Dim iSecond As Double = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iSecond)

PlayHour = iSpan.Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
PlayMin = iSpan.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
PlaySec = iSpan.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

My requirement is to dynamically set a time code in the label by adding the current position hour, minute and second to the recorded time of the movie.

For example the movie file will show the time code as 17:56:33" when loaded, when the playback begins the seconds,minutes and hours (17:56:34, 17:56:35 and so...) should start incrementing in accordance with the actual time of the playback.

Can any one please guide me in the right direction... I am breaking my head on this since quite some time and heading no where...I am quite sure I have to use Timespan for this but don't know how to get this done.

Comment: How are you playing the video? Windows media player control?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Stick this in the tick event of a timer and set the interval to 1...

```
Dim controls As WMPLib.IWMPControls3 = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols
controls.currentPositionTimecode = "[00000]01:00:30.05"
Label1.Text = controls.currentPositionString
```

All you'll need to change is "Label1" and "axWindowsMediaPlayer1". You might want to play around with "[00000]01:00:30.05" to get the format you require; this displays mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

hii add  label to media and this code to timer of track bar

```
       ` TrackBar2.Maximum = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration
        Label3.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString
        TrackBar2.Value = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
        Label4.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.durationString `
```